# Android emulator 30.8.4 fails on MacBook Pro Intel, macOS Big Sur 11.6

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, macos-big-sur

System is running the following:

```
MacBook Pro Intel
Big Sur 11.6
Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Android 11 (R)
Android Emulator 30.8.4
```

When I try to run an AVD Pixel 4a API 30 in the emulator it says:

```
AVD Manager
The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4a_API_30 has terminated.
```

The console shows:

```
Oct 18 20:58:53 moe qemu-system-x86_64[64494]: getattrlist failed for /System/Library/Extensions/AppleIntelKBLGraphicsGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelKBLGraphicsGLDriver: #2: No such file or directory
Oct 18 20:58:53 moe qemu-system-x86_64[64494]: getattrlist failed for /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Resources//GLRendererFloat.bundle/GLRendererFloat: #2: No such file or directory
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the emulator, but no luck.